# Laravel change exceptions message language from French to English

Tags: laravel, exception, message

I have recently downloaded Laravel 5.4.* using composer, I have noticed that the default Exception messages are being displayed in French language, how to change it to English language ?

See highlighted text in the below screenshot

[image: Laravel exception language in French]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially I thought this language issue was related to Laravel, later realized that this also exist in other PHP CMS and frameworks, so thought of updating here.

I fixed this issue by modifying MySQL settings file (i.e.: C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql*\my.ini)

changed

```
# Change your locale here !
lc-messages=fr_FR
```

to

```
# Change your locale here !
lc-messages=en_US
```

If needed restart your wamp server.

You can also set the MySQL session by executing following query.  [Click for more](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-message-language.html)

```
SET lc_messages = 'en_US';
```

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

in your `.env` file change these values

```
APP_LOCALE=en
APP_FALLBACK_LOCALE=en
APP_LOCALE_PHP=en_US
```

also make sure to clear your configurations

```
        composer dumpautoload -o
        php artisan optimize
        php artisan clear-compiled
        php artisan cache:clear
        php artisan route:clear
        php artisan view:clear
        php artisan config:clear
```

Run these commands

Hope this helps

Comment: This code was not there in my .env file, I added it but still I'm getting the same language

Comment: @KArunSingh I have also updated the answer have a look

Comment: Sorry @Mumtaz, I have run all the commands but still issue persist

Comment: @KArunSingh are you using `php artisan serve` to run the server?

Comment: No I'm directly accessing it using url

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a PostgreSQL configuration issue.

Check your `postgresql.conf` file for locale settings, if you set them to English you will get what you want:

```
lc_messages = 'English_United States.1252'                  # locale for system error message strings
lc_monetary = 'English_United States.1252'                  # locale for monetary formatting
lc_numeric = 'English_United States.1252'                   # locale for number formatting
lc_time = 'English_United States.1252'                      # locale for time formatting
```

Here's more info on [locale settings in PosgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/locale.html).

The actual string depends on your system:

> What locales are available on your system under what names depends on
>   what was provided by the operating system vendor and what was
>   installed. On most Unix systems, the command locale -a will provide a
>   list of available locales. Windows uses more verbose locale names,
>   such as German_Germany or Swedish_Sweden.1252, but the principles are
>   the same.

so for Windows it's `English_United States` and *unix usually `en_US`.